# Generate file and replace strings in template file in the generated files

Tags: json, bash, sed, jq, auto-generate

I have a JSON file:

```
{
    "header": {
        "uuid": "c578592a-a751-4993-9060-53f488597e59",
        "timestamp": 1522938800,
        "productionDateTime": "2018-04-05T14:33:20.000+00:00",
        "producers": {
            "operator": null,
            "application": {
                "com.example": {
                    "id": {
                        "string": "1"
                    },
                    "name": {
                        "string": "Test"
                    }
                }
            },
            "station": null,
            "equipment": null,
            "partner": null,
            "flow": null
        },
        "correlationContext": {
            "array": [{
                "correlationId": "98440498-3104-479e-9c99-f4449ba8f4b6",
                "correlationDateTime": {
                    "string": "2018-04-05T14:30:39.000+00:00"
                }
            }]
        }
    },
}
```

I would like to create n files that copy the JSON file but with a random correlationId and correlationDateTime.

Do you have any tips or suggestions? Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you have python in your system?

Comment: Yes, could you give me more deteils?

Comment: @Itqbx, I have provided an solution. Try with that. It is working for me.

Comment: What do you mean by random “correlationDateTime”? Between now and the Big Bang? Now and the beginning of the Unix Epoch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:-

```
#!/bin/bash
alias uid="python -c 'import sys,uuid; sys.stdout.write(uuid.uuid4().hex)' | pbcopy && pbpaste && echo"
dt=$(date "+%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")
# For above two values I am leaving with you. If you have best option please go for it
i=0
while [ $i -le 20 ]
do
  sed  "/correlationId/s/98440498-3104-479e-9c99-f4449ba8f4b6/"$uid"/;s/2018-04-05T14:30:39.000+00:00/"$dt"/" yourJsonFile.json > testcase$i.json
  i=$((i+1))
done
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. However, the line alias uid="python -c 'import sys,uuid; sys.stdout.write(uuid.uuid4().hex)' | pbcopy && pbpaste && echo" don't work for me -> the line correlationId in the generated files is empty ("correlationId": "",) :(

Comment: @itqbx, Just find out a solution to generate the correlationId and change that line. That will solve your issue. Rest everything is fine and I have already tested it. you can simply test it and add line uid="123-456-789-1122-3344-5566" and check.

Comment: Yes, it work perfectly by using the uuidgen command. Thank you for your follow up!

Answer (score 2):

Using `jq` and leaving the generation of appropriate random values as an exercise for the reader:

```
$ jq --arg cid "foo" --arg cdt "bar" '
    .header.correlationContext.array[0]={
        correlationId: $cid,
        correlationDateTime: {string: $cdt}
     }' tmp.json
```